# Can you change the outcome of the game's ending?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

Are there any ingame actions that lead to a change in the ending of Bioshock: Infinite? Similar to how Bioshock 1 and 2 worked, where in 1, if you killed a certain number of Little Sisters or didn't kill any of them, it would significantly impact the story's ending.

Does the same thing apply here? Or is the ending the same every time, no matter what actions you take (ex. throwing ball at couple, picking a brooch, shooting certain people, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, which makes me feel a little bit sad.

There is only few cosmetic changes (for example with like with Cornelius Slate) but you can't change ending as far as I know.

From [Gamespot forum](http://www.gamespot.com/bioshock-infinite/forum/multiple-endings-65798365/)...

> Look up for the Gamespot Lounge interview with Ken Levine, he says
>   that 2k wanted **multiple endings but he said "nope"**.

Also you can watch [on Youtube interview](http://youtu.be/8EbsuHrC0c0?t=4m3s) (4 - 6 min) how Ken Levine say that they wanted to "**make player experiance that he had to make choices**" but also he tells that this **choices not change plot**.

Comment: To be fair, having a single fixed ending regardless of your decisions actually kind of fits the story very well.

Comment: Agree, but Bioshock was famous about multiple endings before Infinite.

Comment: Might just be me but having choices that don't change the ending might be the point of the game. Never changing. This is lampshaded almost at the end of the game.

Comment: I agree that one definite ending is befitting for the story, yet I would have liked it too if replays could change the ending a slight bit at a time. As far as I know though, the ending is set in stone, but every individual players interpretation and imagination is not :)

Comment: Infinite kind of has this air of *You can do whatever, that won't change a thing* just like when Elizabeth and Booker tried to finish their quest with Fitzroy. In the end, they never got a hold of those weapons, regardless of how many tears they went through.